# Django reverse lookup to get latest

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model structure as below,

```
ACTIVE_STATUS = ['waiting', 'loading', 'starting', 'running', 'stopping']
INACTIVE_STATUS = ['stopped', 'finished', 'failed', 'lost']
ALL_STATUS = ACTIVE_STATUS + INACTIVE_STATUS


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Job(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='jobs')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=zip(ALL_STATUS, ALL_STATUS), max_length=20)
```

How can I annotate the "latest timestamp and its status" into Task queryset?

I have managed to obtain the latest timestamp by,

```
Task.objects.annotate(latest_ts=models.Max(models.F('job__timestamp')))
```

So, how can I get the corresponding `status`?

## Update-1

The utmost aim of this query is to sort the `Task` queryset in

1. with zero Jobs ( say `Task.objects.filter(job__isnull=True)` )
2. latest_job=='running'

## Update-2

TaskManager class that used to obtain the sorted queryset

```
class TaskManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        latest_job = models.Max(models.F('job__timestamp'))

        latest_status = models.Subquery(
            Job.objects.filter(
                task_id=models.OuterRef('pk')
            ).values('status').order_by('-timestamp')[:1]
        )

        qs_order = models.Case(
            models.When(job__isnull=True, then=models.Value(2)),
            models.When(latest_status='running', then=models.Value(1)),
            default=models.Value(0),
            output_field=models.IntegerField()
        )

        return qs.annotate(latest_job=latest_job, latest_status=latest_status, qs_order=qs_order).order_by('-qs_order')
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Comment: @Does that mean you want items with no job *in* or out of the queryset?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem want items with no job ***in*** the queryset

Comment: if you use `models.When(job__isnull=True, then=models.Value(2)),`, then this will however result in a JOIN, so the same `Task` will be repeated that many times as there are `Job`s present for that `Task`.

Comment: Oops... What about the `Count('job')` ? and later I can replace the `job__isnull=True....` statement with **`models.When(count_jobs=0, then=models.Value(2))`**

Comment: that is also an option, yes.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62807117/12578202).  BTW, now, I am bit concern about the performance.

Answer (score 5):

You can work with a [**`Subquery`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Task.objects.annotate(
    latest_status=Subquery(
        Job.objects.filter(
            task_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('status').order_by('-timestamp')[:1]
    )
)
```

Based on this, you can probably also filter on the latest status:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Task.objects.annotate(
    latest_status=Subquery(
        Job.objects.filter(
            task_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('status').order_by('-timestamp')[:1]
    )
).filter(
    Q(jobs=None) | Q(latest_status='running')
)
```

or we can order by the existance of a `Job`, etc. with:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Exists, ExpressionWrapper, Max, Q
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Task.objects.annotate(
    latest_status=Subquery(
        Job.objects.filter(
            task_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('status').order_by('-timestamp')[:1]
    ),
    latest_job=Max('jobs__timestamp')
).order_by(
    Exists(Job.objects.filter(task_id=OuterRef('pk'))).asc(),
    ExpressionWrapper(Q(latest_status='running'), output_field=BooleanField()).asc(),
    'pk'
)
```

It might be a good idea to filter eventually on the primary key to make the ordering *deterministic*.

Comment: Thanks, and seems its working. Unfortunately, I forget to put my utmost scenario in the OP. Would you mind checking the OP again?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu: can you see if the filtering resolves the problem?

Comment: I don't think so, because I am pushing this QuerySet into a *DRF ListAPI* (pagination enabled)

Comment: I didn't get any errors, but, does this include `latest_status != 'running'` ? (I think, `No`) Apart from that, this is a ***order by** issue, right?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu: normally it should not include `Task`s where the latest status is running no. You can add a `.order_by('pk')` for example to ensure that if the jobs do not change meanwhile, the next page will continue where the previous ended.

Comment: I am trying to sort the queryset based on custom condition(s). Probably, you will get more idea of what I am trying to do. (see `update-2`)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu: see edit. It might be better to also sort on the pk in case of a tie breaker, otherwise in the next query the ordering of tasks without a job itself might differ for example.

Answer (score 1):

Willem's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801980/12578202) looks promising what I want, but, I have managed to obtain the ordering by annotating the count of jobs.

This is the model manager at the end,

```
class TaskManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        latest_job = models.Max(models.F('jobs__timestamp'))

        latest_status = models.Subquery(
            Job.objects.filter(
                task_id=models.OuterRef('pk')
            ).values('status').order_by('-timestamp')[:1]
        )
        job_count = models.Count('jobs')

        qs_order = models.Case(
            models.When(job_count=0, then=models.Value(2)),
            models.When(latest_status='running', then=models.Value(1)),
            default=models.Value(0),
            output_field=models.IntegerField()
        )

        return qs.annotate(job_count=job_count,
                           latest_job=latest_job,
                           latest_status=latest_status,
                           qs_order=qs_order
                           ).order_by('-qs_order', '-pk')
```

**Result screenshot**

[image]